# bash script version of forfiles

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file, automation

I'm currently converting a DOS batch script to a shell script and while I have 99% of it working, one part I cannot figure out how to convert over.

In the batch file, I have a line that looks like

```
forfiles -p "t:\jeopardy" -s -m *.* /D -3 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

How would I write that for a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, this will delete files without prompting

```
find /jeopardy -mtime 3 -name "*.*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

To be prompted before files are deleted, try the variation of above

```
find /jeopardy -mtime 3 -name "*.*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

NOTE: I have used the Linux variant of the path `t:\jeopardy`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) what this command does is recursively searching in `t:\jeopardy` directory all for files which are at last three days "old" and removing them. So unix equivalent would be something like:

```
find /jeopardy -mtime 3 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Both methods worked, but nsilent22's was shorter and first, so I marked his as the answer.  Thank you both for making my hair a little less gray :)

Comment: @user2274612: To be honest vmachan's answer is 3 minutes "older", which means he was first :)

Comment: @nsilent22 I just looked at the time given by hovering over the "answered x hours ago" text, and yours is 20:26:59, while his is 20:23:59. That is **exactly** 3 minutes